# How to get Desktop.getDesktop().open() and Runtime.getRuntime().exec() working from the servlet under Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, exec

My purpose is to open a directory and bring it into view from the servelt under **Tomcat**. The request to the servlet comes from the same machine where the server is running. Here is the servlet code:

```java
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DirOpener extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");

        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("D:\\tmp"));
        resp.getWriter().print("done!");
    }
}
```

During application testing and remote debugging with **Tomcat** starting from *IntelliJ IDEA*, everything works fine: I just click the link in the browser, the servlet opens a directory and responds with "done!". However, when I deploy the exploded application artifact under *\webapps* and start **Tomcat** as a Windows service from *Apache Commons Daemon Service Manager*, I get an exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to open D:\tmp. Error message: Ошибка при выполнении приложения-сервера

    java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(WDesktopPeer.java:107)
    java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.open(WDesktopPeer.java:81)
    java.desktop/java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:429)
    DirOpener.doGet(DirOpener.java:13)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Also, I tried to replace `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("D:\\tmp"));` in code with the line `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer D:\\tmp");` but again, everything works fine when **Tomcat** starts from the console, and fails when it runs as a service. However, this time no exception is thrown: the servlet just responds with "done!", but doesn't open a directory (actually, it creates a process in the task manager, but doesn't bring it into view). Similar things happen when I try to `exec` batch-files or another program (such as notepad.exe or calc.exe) from the servelt.

Could you, please, help me to figure out where is the problem and how to fix it?

UPDATED:

When you run **Tomcat** as a Windows service, there is a Log On option available to *"Allow service to interact with desktop"*. Though even when checked, this option seem to have no effect and the problem still exists.

UPDATED 2:

Well, the issue seems to be not about what **Tomcat** can or can't do. It's all about Windows services. **You just cannot use Windows serivce to start a GUI exe program no matter what the value of the "allow service to interact with desktop" property is set to** (and, honestly, I don't understand what does this option exist for).

One possible workaround to this problem is to create and run a sort of "controller", so that a web-app and the "controller" can communicate to each other via plain socket connection. In this case, web-app might delegate some tasks it can't do with the desktop to the "controller". Another option is not to run Tomcat as a Windows service and start it from the command line instead.

Comment: What is the underlying problem that you want to solve with having a webserver start a desktop program. This is quite an unusual idea, not commonly done, and rather a hazard in terms of user access rights, maintenance and DOS options. You should rather attempt to solve the problem (whatever it is) through HTTP(S) and forget about direct desktop interaction. See [this description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for identifying the reason for me asking for the underlying problem.

Comment: I just tried to use my web-app as a replacement for GUI java-program, so that not to sink myself into all those Swing's panes and layouts. I understand that it's abnormal idea for a web app server like Tomcat to open local directories on the server machine and start desktop programs like notepad, explorer, word or whatever, but in my case the client is supposed to be on the same machine where the server is running and I'm ready to take the risks. However, direct desktop interaction is possible only when Tomcat starts from the command line and not as a Windows service.